# How to separate columns with indefinite number of spaces

Tags: python, split, multiple-columns

I have a text file with some columns, and dependeng on the number of characters of each column it takes different spaces to separate from the following column.

Example:

```
1        1.2345  5.2            4.3
24.4641  63.548  7.9288         2.12
8.1541   5.72    9.14186158     5.7
2.4      6549.2  5.7            14
```

How can I make a Python program that separates them regardless of the number of spaces? Split isn't working..

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by separates them? do yo want them in a list?

Comment: "split isn't working". No, it should work. Show us what you're trying.

Comment: split() with no parameters will split on any/all whitespace. So it shouldn't matter that they have different amounts. If that's not working then something else is wrong with your assumptions.

Comment: Are you sure they are not `\t` tabs?

Comment: @corn3lius even with tabs split() should work

Comment: I was using  line.split('   ') sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
row = '1        1.2345  5.2            4.3'
row_digits = re.findall('\d+\.*\d*', row)
```

Using regular expressions guarantees you will get the numbers regardless of whether they're separated by spaces or tabs (or any other characters for that matter).

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved my problem